# Evaluate $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{r= 0}^{n} \frac{r}{n^2+ r} $

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

$$  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \sum_{r= 0}^{n} \frac{r}{n^2+ r} $$

My attempt 
Divide  Nr and Dr by $n^2$ 
$$  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \sum_{r= 0}^{n} \frac{r/n^2}{1+ r/n^2}  $$
=0

Is it correct or not

Comment: Compare this sum with $\sum r/n^2$.

Comment: Hint: For all $r$ in this range we have
$$\frac r{(n+1)^2}\le\frac r{n^2+r}\le\frac r{n^2}.$$

Comment: This is solved in [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1908626p13067318). Haven't found it on our site yet. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1585305/11619) is close (exact same estimates work).

Comment: @metamorphy Paramanand Singh showed how to do that :-)

Comment: Why there is downvote to my question

Answer (score 4):

No it's not as n start to tends infinity the sum does not remain negligible. We can use sandwich theorm that is

if f(x)$\le$h(x)$\le$g(x) and $lim_{x\rightarrow c}$ g(x) =$lim_{x\rightarrow c}$ f(x) = l then $lim_{x\rightarrow c}$ h(x)=l

For $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$

$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{r}{n^2}$ $\ge$ $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{r}{n^2+r}$ $\ge$ $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{r}{n^2+n}$

Therefore

$\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}$ $\ge$ $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{r}{n^2 + r}$ $\ge$ $\frac{n(n+1)}{2n(n+1)}$

$\frac{1}{2}$ $\ge$  $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{r}{n^2+r }$ $\ge$  $\frac{1}{2}.$

Hence answer is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: You should fix your latex. Otherwise things are OK and +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach based on Riemann sum. The expression under limit can be written as $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{rn}{n^2+r}$$ and note that $$t_r=\frac{nr} {n^2+r}\in\left[\frac{r-1}{n},\frac{r}{n}\right]$$ and hence the sum under limit is a Riemann sum for partition $$\{0,1/n,2/n,\dots,(n-1)/n,1\}$$ of $[0,1]$ with tag points $t_r$ and function $f(x) =x$. The desired limit is then equal to $\int_{0}^{1}x\,dx=1/2$.

Comment: LOL. You don't need to evaluate a function at the end points of the subintervals to get a Riemann sum.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: yes, end points are most common, but definition of Riemann sum provides for a more general approach.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh can solve using that method were we change $1/n $ to $ dx$ and $r/n$ to $ x$.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar: it's best not to think in that manner. Better learn definition of a Riemann sum and try to see if your sum under limit is in that form or  not.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar: see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3522906/72031

Answer (score 2):

The limit and the summation cannot be exchanged. For example, Dominated Convergence does not help: consider the maximum for each $r$:
$$
\sup_{n\ge r}\frac{r}{n^2+r}=\frac1{r+1}
$$
since $\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty\frac1{r+1}=\infty$, any dominating series diverges.

---

In fact
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r}{n^2+r}
&\ge\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r}{n^2+n}\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r}{n^2+r}
&\le\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r}{n^2}\\
&=\frac12\left(1+\frac1n\right)
\end{align}
$$
The Squeeze Theorem then says
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r}{n^2+r}=\frac12
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffe,10px]{\sum_{r = 0}^{n}{r \over n^{2} + r}} =
n + 1 - n^{2}\sum_{r = 0}^{n}{1 \over r + n^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
n + 1 - n^{2}\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over r + n^{2}} -
{1 \over r + n + 1 + n^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
n + 1 - n^{2}\bracks{\Psi\pars{n^{2} + n + 1} - \Psi\pars{n^{2}}}
\\[1cm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,&
n + 1
\\[2mm] &\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
-n^{2}\braces{\bracks{\ln\pars{n^{2} + n + 1} -
{1 \over 2n^{2} + 2n + 2}} -
\bracks{\ln\pars{n^{2}} - {1 \over 2n^{2}}}}
\\[1cm] = &\
n + 1 - n^{2}\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over n} + {1 \over n^{2}}} +
{n^{2} \over 2n^{2} + 2n + 2} - {1 \over 2}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,&\
n + 1 - n^{2}\bracks{\pars{{1 \over n} + {1 \over n^{2}}} -
{1 \over 2}\pars{{1 \over n} + {1 \over n^{2}}}^{2}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,&\
n + 1 - \bracks{n + 1 -
n^{2}\,{1 \over 2}\pars{1 \over n}^{2}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\,
\bbx{\large{1 \over 2}}
\end{align}